# I need to link two of my tables together and return only the highest group average

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am trying to link two of my tables together, I have my `Artist` Table and my `CD` table. My `CD` Table contains a number of CD Entrys, complete with `CD.cdID`, `CD.artID`, `CD.cdTitle`, `CD.cdPrice` and `CD.cdGenre`. My `Artist` table contains, `Artist.artID`, `Artist.artName`. I am trying to return the Artist.artName which has the highest average price for all of their CDs in the `CD` Table.

This is my code for this so far. So far it is pulling the maximum average CD prices by `CD.artID` but I am not sure how to combine this so that I can display the `Artist.artName` name instead of `CD.artID`:

```
SELECT AVG(cdPrice) as cdPrice, artID
FROM CD
GROUP BY artID
HAVING AVG(cdPrice) = (SELECT MAX(cdPrice) FROM 
(SELECT AVG(cdPrice) as cdPrice FROM CD GROUP BY artID) A)
```

I am using MySQL via PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` after joining the tables - the same rules apply, viz all non-aggregated columns must be grouped. To find the highest averaging artist only, you can replace the having with a simple ORDER and LIMIT:

```
SELECT AVG(cd.cdPrice) as avgPrice, a.artName
FROM CD cd INNER JOIN Artist a
on cd.artID = a.artID
GROUP BY a.artName
ORDER BY avgPrice DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48e9d/1)